# HTML email with CID images, is there a way to repeat the background or stretch it to 100% width?

Tags: css, html-email

I am trying to put a 1px repeating background image in a TD in an HTML email.
Unfortunately, with the CSS attribute and with the HTML background attribute, the image isn't showing.
Is there a safe cross-client solution that works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad truth is that if you want your email to look allright in Outlook of newer variety, background images are a no go. The best thing we do is to use solid background colour and make table image headers and borders that fade out within the image itself.